# Access batch environment variables inside Perl script

Tags: perl, batch-file, jenkins

I am trying to send the Jenkins artifacts to shared drive post build activity using a Perl script, but from the code below the `%versionName%` value is already set as an environment variable from the batch script.

I don’t how to pass the environment variables into a Perl script. I am getting the output `Motiv_Android__V_%versionName%`, but I am expecting `Motiv_Android__V_1.X.X.X`. 
The value of `%versionName%` is `1.X.X.X`.

```
use warnings;

use File::Copy;
use File::Copy::Recursive qw (dircopy);


my $source_dir   = 'C:\test';
my $target_dir   = 'Z:\main\term\ban\test';
my $artifact_dir = 'C:\Users\lavana\Projects\MyApplication\';

my ( %versionName ) = @ARGV;

$Artifact_name = "Motiv_Android_\_V\_%versionName%";

print "artifact $Artifact_name\n";

mkdir $Artifact_name;

opendir( my $DIR, $source_dir ) || die "can't opendir $source_dir: $!"; 

my @files = readdir( $DIR );

foreach my $t ( sort grep( /^.*\.apk$/, @files ) ) {

    if ( "$source_dir/$t" ) {
        copy "$source_dir/$t", "./$Artifact_name/$t"
        dircopy("$artifact_dir/$Artifact_name","$target_dir/$Artifact_name");
    }
}

closedir($DIR);
```

Comment: To indent code, you press tab not return :P

Comment: The code you show is not your real program. The string `'C:\Users\lavana\Projects\MyApplication\'` escapes the closing single quote, resulting in a multi-line string which ends at the apostrophe in `"can't opendir $source_dir: $!"` and making nonsense of the rest of your code. If you want help with your problem then it's best not to lie to us. Please post your real code.

Answer (score 0):

The environment is accessed via the `%ENV` hash.

Replace

```
$Artifact_name = "Motiv_Android_\_V\_%versionName%";
```

with

```
$Artifact_name = "Motiv_Android_\_V\_$ENV{versionName}";
```

or

```
$Artifact_name = "Motiv_Android_\_V\_" . $ENV{versionName};
```

Note that those slashes are useless, so you could use

```
$Artifact_name = "Motiv_Android__V_" . $ENV{versionName};
```

Comment: I am creating folder and files are not copying in my $target_dir.

Comment: can you anyone advise please

Answer (score -2):

Perhaps [ENV perl module](https://perldoc.perl.org/Env.html) or [ENV associative arrays](https://alvinalexander.com/perl/edu/articles/pl020002)?

Comment: I want to access the batch environment variable before my Perl runs i ran .bat file which is set environment variable and the same value want to retrieve inside Perl program. any solution please ?

Comment: Please don't link to articles that use the phrase "associative arrays". They have been called "hashes" since Perl 5 was released in 1994. Any article that calls them associative arrays is either very old or written by someone whose Perl knowledge is outdated.

Comment: In any case, every array is "associative" and the name is meaningless.

Comment: Please read [*Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/170274).

Comment: @ikegami: I know that "associative array" is a good description of what a Perl hash actually is. My point is that it's a term that the community moved away from over twenty years ago and nowadays, its use in an article should be seen as a red flag.

Comment: @DaveCross: Indeed, and the term is a gross and lazy one anyway. [`xlinux.nist.gov`](https://xlinux.nist.gov/dads/HTML/assocarray.html) has "***associative array*** *(data structure)* ***Definition:*** *A collection of items that are randomly accessible by a key, often a string*" which applies equally to an ordinary array, so the label is horribly ambiguous.

Comment: @David Cross, I disagree. I use "associative array" to refer to hashes in a polyglotal context such as when introducing people to Perl, and that appears to be the audience of that article. That way, everyone's on equal footing, because we can use a language-independent term with a well understood [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). That way, someone coming from another language could associate hashes with `Dictionary` or whatever associative arrays with which they are familiar.

Comment: So if they want an associative array (e.g. to insert arbitrary elements, something an array can't do), this would teach them they want a hash.

Answer (score -2):

To get to an environment variable in perl you should use %ENV, or the Env perl module. For your example, this is probably the easiest:

```
my $version_name = $ENV{versionName}
```

Comment: The variable you're talking about is a hash, so it's called `%ENV`, not `$ENV` and you use braces, not parentheses, to access the values - `$ENV{versionName}`.

Comment: Oi. Fixed. I haven't written perl in a while and syntax got crossed. My fingers don't always do what I ask them. And I just screwed up the reference to the hash. Thanks for the correction.